# CSS Grid, Auto Fill + Widths Set By Content

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I want each button to retain its unique width (currently based on text width), and for the buttons to automatically be placed in the next row when there's no more room horizontally.

Using `grid-auto-flow: column` allows for the buttons to retain their width, but then they do not wrap. Using  `grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(1rem, 15rem))` allows them to wrap, but then they lose their individual widths.

Codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/jovial-shannon-btp3x?file=/src/styles.css

```css
.grid {
  margin-top: 1rem;
  margin-left: 0.1rem;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(1rem, 11.3rem));
  max-width: 100%;
  grid-row-gap: 2.5rem;
  grid-column-gap: 2.5rem;
}

.button {
  padding: 1rem;
  outline: 1px solid rgba(110, 110, 110, 0.34);
  color: white;
  background-color: #1d1f1f;
  font-family: Calibri;
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <button class="button">
        <span class="button-text">
          ab
        </span>
      </button>
  <button class="button">
        <span class="button-text">
          abcd
        </span>
      </button>
  <button class="button">
        <span class="button-text">
          abcdefg
        </span>
      </button>
  <button class="button">
        <span class="button-text">
          abcdefghij
        </span>
      </button>
  <button class="button">
        <span class="button-text">
          abcdefghijklm
        </span>
      </button>
  <button class="button">
        <span class="button-text">
          abcdefghijklmnop
        </span>
      </button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want each button to retain its unique width (currently based on text width), and for the buttons to automatically be placed in the next row when there's no more room horizontally.
>
> Using  `grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(1rem, 15rem))` allows them to wrap, but then they lose their individual widths.

Well, the buttons are contained within columns. And columns (like rows) have fixed lengths across the grid container.

It appears that what you're actually requesting is flexible column lengths that would adjust to fit the varying widths of their cells. That wouldn't be a grid and, therefore, is not possible in grid layout.

Here's an illustration of what I'm saying:

[image]

A grid is a matrix of intersecting fixed-width columns and fixed-height rows. You can adjust the width of the buttons within their tracks, but that would only lead to unsightly gaps between them.

---

> Using `grid-auto-flow: column` allows for the buttons to retain their width, but then they do not wrap.

Yes, because with `grid-auto-flow: column` (and no defined rows), all buttons exist in a single row and have their own column.

[image]

To your second point, they have no reason to wrap without `auto-fill` or `auto-fit`, and even if they could, you would then encounter the same problem described in the previous section.

---

Consider flexbox, which isn't limited by column and row tracks. Although you'll need to hack your way to gutters, as the `gap` properties with flex are currently supported in Firefox only.

```css
.grid {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  row-gap: 2.5rem;     /* FF only */
  column-gap: 2.5rem;  /* FF only */
}

.button {
  max-width: 11.3rem;
  min-width: 1rem;
  padding: 1rem;
  outline: 1px solid rgba(110, 110, 110, 0.34);
  color: white;
  background-color: #1d1f1f;
  font-family: Calibri;
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <button class="button">
    <span class="button-text">
      ab
    </span>
  </button>
  <button class="button">
    <span class="button-text">
      abcd
    </span>
  </button>
  <button class="button">
    <span class="button-text">
      abcdefg
    </span>
  </button>
  <button class="button">
    <span class="button-text">
      abcdefghij
    </span>
  </button>
  <button class="button">
    <span class="button-text">
      abcdefghijklm
    </span>
  </button>
  <button class="button">
    <span class="button-text">
      abcdefghijklmnop
    </span>
  </button>
</div>
```

[jsFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/wkh80tcp/)

Comment: Your quote, "That wouldn't be a grid and, therefore, is not possible in grid layout." is unfortunately way off the mark of what the definition of "grid" is by the new(er) CSS Grid specification. The new specification isn't about making same-width columns and same-height rows; if that were so, we would not have at our disposal value parameters such as 'max-content' and 'min-content'. We would not be able to intermingle percentages, rems, ems, pixels and other variable widths to different columns in the same grid. [This website will be helpful](http://gridbyexample.com)

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is "grid-auto-flow" which can be set to column or row. For a quick visual reference, [MDN's page is a good one](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-auto-flow).

CSS Grid is meant as a layout tool, much like we had for print materials way back before the internet. Columns do *not* need to be the same width and rows, likewise, do *not* have to be the same height. In fact, CSS Grid is literally the layout tool we were hoping to have two decades ago because laying things out on a rigid *every-column-is-the-same-width* foundation gets redundant and boring.

Furthermore, CSS grid allows things like overlap, media-query-less layout adjustments and auto placement, and I could go on and on.

Bonus tip: look up grid areas. [Read about them here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-area).